# css text not aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with centering the text inside of my div. Can someone please help me align this text to the center of the box

[image: http://imgur.com/iMS7nrG]

Here is my css:

```
#btc-container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background: orange;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    border-style: ridge;
}

#btc-price {
    color: black;
    font-family: digital-7;
    font-size: 30px;
    alignment-adjust:middle;
}
```

and here is what I have in the HTML:

```
<div id="btc-container">
    <div id="btc-price">930.1234</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your css like this:

```
#btc-price {
color: black;
font-family: digital-7;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px; // or what ever is your button height 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to center align the text use `text-align: center`. To vertically align it gets more complicated (specially if you want cross-browser and/or need to support older browsers), but an easy way to vertically center text inside a div if you know it's only one line is using `line-height` like `line-height:50px` in your case

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/uN2Dt/

```
#btc-price {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/QXT5B/

The changed CSS:

```
#btc-container {
height: 40px;
width: 130px;
background: orange;
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 25px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 0px;
border-style: ridge;
padding: 5px 15px;
text-align: center
}
```